# Given the quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the quadratic polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$, find a new polynomial with coefficients expressed in terms $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that the product and the sum of its zeros will be the sum and the product, respectively, of the zeros of the original polynomial.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that for the quadratic polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$, the sum of the roots is $-\dfrac{b}a$ while the product of the roots is $\dfrac{c}a$. Now you want a quadratic whose sum is $\dfrac{c}a$ and the product is $-\dfrac{b}a$. Hence the quadratic you are after is
$$\alpha \left(y^2 - \dfrac{c}ay - \dfrac{b}a\right)$$ where $\alpha$ is some constant. Since you want one such polynomial, we can choose $\alpha = a$, and this gives us
$$ay^2 - cy - b$$